# How do I create variables in R that count the number of values of one variable by another variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, count

This is my data:

```
    Name          Grade
1     John Smith    C     
2     John Smith    B       
3     John Smith    C      
4     Jane Doe      A     
5     Jane Doe      C     
6     Lisa Brown    B
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
     Name           A  B  C
1     John Smith    0  1  2
4     Jane Doe      1  0  1  
6     Lisa Brown    0  1  0
```

I know I can get this as a table in the console by using the table or with function, but it won't store this way as a dataframe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions:

1. Use `tabyl()` from the `janitor` package:

   ```
    library(janitor)

    tabyl(df, name, grade) 

         name A B C
     Jane Doe 1 0 1
   John Smith 0 1 2
   Lisa Brown 0 1 0
   ```
2. Use `pivot_wider()` from `tidyr`:
   * Note: Updated with better syntax from Darren Tsai's answer.

   ```
   library(tidyr)

   df %>%
      pivot_wider(id_cols = name, 
                  names_from = grade,
                  names_sort = TRUE,
                  values_from = grade,
                  values_fn = length,
                  values_fill = 0) 

    # A tibble: 3 x 4
      name           A     B     C
      <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1 John Smith     0     1     2
    2 Jane Doe       1     0     1
    3 Lisa Brown     0     1     0
   ```

Comment: Hi, I see your original `pivot_wider()` version which is different from my idea. You add an additional column before pivoting it to wide, which is different from my idea. You cannot copy my version as yours without my approval, right?

Comment: Hi - no offense intended.  In my experience if it's the same method/intuition but yours is better syntax, the right thing to do is to update the syntax in the answer that OP credited, and just make sure I'm crediting you.  That keeps answers more consolidated over time.  I don't actually think we were suggesting a different approach, I just forgot that you could use `length` as the `values_fn` operation and skip the extra step of adding a count column.  If you have a different opinion, I'm happy to let this comment stand as a note acknowledging you used `length` initially - nice idea!

Comment: I think creating a new column and then setting `values_fn = sum` in `pivot_wider()` is a different idea from setting `values_fn = length` directly. In my experience, whether you forgot the latter or not, if somebody provide a more concise or better version of your code, you can keep yours in the post or delete it, but don't copy the new one to your post because you don't have the ***"priority"***.

Answer (score 0):

A `base` solution with `table()` and `as.data.frame.matrix()`, which returns a `data.frame` object with row names. You can adjust the row names as a new column easily.

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))

#            A B C
# Jane Doe   1 0 1
# John Smith 0 1 2
# Lisa Brown 0 1 0
```

You can also achieve it by `pivot_wider()` from `tidyr` with only one call.

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(df, names_from = Grade,
                names_sort = TRUE,
                values_from = Grade,
                values_fill = 0,
                values_fn = length)

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   Name           A     B     C
#   <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
# 1 John Smith     0     1     2
# 2 Jane Doe       1     0     1
# 3 Lisa Brown     0     1     0
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("John Smith", "John Smith", "John Smith", 
"Jane Doe", "Jane Doe", "Lisa Brown"), Grade = c("C", "B", "C", 
"A", "C", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```